# How do you properly cite an advertisement from a website online in APA formatting?

Tags: citations, citation-style, formatting

I can't find an answer to this question anywhere. How do you properly cite an advertisement from a website online in APA formatting?

Is it just:

Company. (Year, Month Day of Ad Retrieval). Ad title [Advertisement]. Title of webpage. Name of website. Retrieved from URL

Answer (score 1):

On top of the links shared by @nsinghs, you can also check [University of Lincoln](https://guides.library.lincoln.ac.uk/c.php?g=110736&p=1211272). Also, you can refer to [this](http://www.citationmachine.net/apa/cite-a-advertisement/manual) link that will create APA style citations for you based on the information you fill for an ad (the ad can be in a newspaper, in a magazine, online, or on TV/radio).

Answer (score 0):

I found this from [Columbia College, Vancouver, Canada](https://columbiacollege-ca.libguides.com/apa/advert). Look at their "Video Advertisement from YouTube Posted by Advertiser" section, I think it should be similar to a website advertisement.

Name of Company That Owns the Product. (Year, Month Day Posted). *Name of advertisement* [Advertisement]. Retrieved from URL

Comment: What should I do if the advertisement doesn't have a name?

Comment: I am not sure, but assuming you are referring to a company regarding that product, shouldn't it just be the product name?

Comment: @PikachuIsCute You could try citing the ad’s file name if you can’t find a name for the advertisement campaign.